# Como actualizar este codigo a PDO

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

Hola estoy intentando actualizar una tabla en **MySQL** con **jQuery**, con consultas a **PDO**. Aquí tengo el código que no se como actualizar:

```
while($registro2 = mysql_fetch_array($registro)){
        $tabla = $tabla.'<tr>
                            <td>'.$registro2['nomb_prod'].'</td>
                            <td>'.$registro2['tipo_prod'].'</td>
                            <td>S/. '.$registro2['precio_unit'].'</td>
                            <td>S/. '.$registro2['precio_dist'].'</td>
                            <td>'.fechaNormal($registro2['fecha_reg']).'</td>
                            <td><a href="javascript:editarProducto('.$registro2['id_prod'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a> <a href="javascript:eliminarProducto('.$registro2['id_prod'].');" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></a></td>
                          </tr>';       
    }
```

En mi caso solo se me ocurre hacer un `fetchAll()` y un `forEach` pero no se si estaría bien.

Comment: "_En mi caso solo se me ocurre hacer un fetchAll() y hacer un foreach_" En teoría debería funcionar sin problemas y estaría bien. ¿Has probado a hacerlo?¿funciona?¿te falla?

Comment: Y la consulta?, solo pones el código para mostrar los datos. A parte de eso `mysql_fetch_array($registro)` no se usa con `PDO`, debería ser con `fetch()`

Comment: Si vas a la documentación de mysql_fetch_array() , puedes ver una advertencia que te puede guiar: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Coincido en que falta información a la pregunta recuerda lo que se describe en [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Le falta un poco de información a la pregunta. Sin embargo, con el motivo de ayudarte, te puedo dar los siguientes consejos y en parte responder tu pregunta:

**1. No utilices los driver mysql**

Los driver "mysql" se encuentran deshabilitados en las versiones más recientes de PHP y es probable que si es que subes tu código a un servidor compartido, no puedas utilizarlo debido a esto (además de que sus funciones han sido declaradas como obsoletas). Se que la pregunta justamente va por cómo re-emplezar el código a PDO, pero no quiero dejar de mencionar esto por si alguna otra persona lo lee.

**2. Hacer un while para leer registros es una práctica bastante común**

Hacer un while es una práctica bastante común al momento de leer información de una base de datos por lo cual está bien la lógica que presentas y muestras en el código.

**3. Puedes utilizar PDO o MySQLi**

No solo puedes utilizar PDO, también puedes utilizar MySQLi el cual es bastante parecido al driver MySQL y posiblemente no tengas que cambiar mucho si es que optas por este último.

**4. Trabaja orientado a objetos**

El código actual utiliza el driver "mysql" y no está orientado a objetos. Como consejo, te recomiendo siempre utilizar los drivers y trabajarlos orientado a objectos. Obviamente, esto dependerá del contexto en que estés.

Con respecto a la pregunta en concreto, aventurándome sin haber visto el resto del código, podría quedar algo similar a lo siguiente (asumiendo que en otro lugar creaste la conexión y todo lo necesario):

```
$sentencia = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE id = :id');
$sentencia->execute(array('id'=>$valor_id));

while($registro2 = $sentencia->fetch()){
  //código para mostrar $registro2 y su contenido...    
}
```

Dejo un enlace en el cual justamente hay una comparativa entre estos tres (mysql, PDO y mysqli) y se muestra cómo utilizar cada uno. Espero les sirva para aclarar dudas.

http://blog.aulaformativa.com/conectar-php-con-mysql/

Comment: Es importante ayudar al OP a que complete su pregunta, de esta manera será de mayor utilidad para la comunidad.